# Why am I unable to edit questions?

Tags: support, design, editing

I have noticed that since the last few days, I am unable to make edits to questions. The `edit` option below the question is disabled, although `share` and `flag` are available (see below screenshot).

[image: Edit is grayed out]

I am able to edit *answers* though. Hence, it doesn't look like I have been banned from editing, besides I don't recall doing anything "bad" on this site to warrant such a ban.

Is this a bug with the site? If not, have I been banned from editing questions? If so, I would like to know why, so that I can avoid doing it in future.

**Update**

One such question where I notice this issue is the following:  [Can a new employer legally change my start date?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/40129/3192)

I realised that I don't see this problem on other questions. There was a bit of confirmation bias at play here. I tried editing *one* question yesterday (still trying to recall what that question was) and saw the option disabled. I decided to edit one question today (the one above), and saw the option disabled again. I just jumped to the conclusion that this option is disabled for me entirely.

Comment: Does this happen with all questions or just certain ones?  (If the latter, got some links?)  And main or meta?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Posted my response as update. Seems odd that the option is disabled on specific questions only (and these questions are not locked/closed/on hold/anything special).

Comment: Another Workplace.SE question where edits seem to be disabled pending an edit (by the OP themselves!?) : [Interview rescheduled by employer two hours before the meeting](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87683/interview-rescheduled-by-employer-two-hours-before-the-meeting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, that's peculiar.

In the example you linked to, there is one edit pending already.  If I attempt to edit that question, I'm presented with the pending edit for review.  The system can only handle one pending edit at a time, so that needs to be cleared before another edit can be made.

You don't yet have enough reputation to review (or directly make) edits, so the system can't ask you to handle that pending edit first.  So it just punts and doesn't let you submit the edit at all, which is a little confusing.

Do you get anything useful in the tooltip if you hover over the edit link?  A general guideline on SE is: if you don't understand what you're looking at it, try hovering.  Yeah, we all have to stumble over that and learn it; sorry.  (If there's nothing helpful in the tooltip, please update the question with what you do see and maybe we can at least get that changed.)

Comment: Thanks for that, I did try hovering over the link, but there was no tooltip. I can't confirm this now since that question has already been edited. The next time something like this happens, I will double-check if there was indeed no tooltip.